# How to set an array of custom objects?

Tags: arrays, class, object, excel, vba

How do I set an array of a custom object that is inside of another custom object? Like the following:

This is Class Licit:

```
'Class Licit

Private LObj() As Obj

Sub RedimObj(index As Integer)
    ReDim Preserve LObj(index)
End Sub

Public Property Let SetObjConlicit(ByVal index As Integer, ByVal ObjConlicit As Double)
    LObj(index).ObConlicita = ObjConlicit
End Property

Public Property Get GetObjConlicit(index As Integer) As Double
    GetObjConlicit = LObj(index).ObConlicita
End Property
```

This is Class Obj (not created yet the set/let properties):

```
'Class Obj
Public ObConlicita As Double
Public Obgrupo As Integer
Public ObitemNum As Integer
Public Obdescr As String
Public ObvalMax As Double
Public Obobs As String
```

And this is my routine to call:

```
Public Licita As Licit

sub run()
Set Licita = New Licit

NumObjetos = 3
Licita.RedimObj (NumObjetos)
For i = 0 To NumObjetos - 1
    Licita.SetObjConlicit(i) = i
Next i

end sub
```

But I get an error on this line
    LObj(index).ObConlicita = ObjConlicit
whentrying to set the value.

The error i get is:

> 'Run-Time Error 91
>   Object Variable or With Block variable not set'

Anyone can help on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What language is this, VB.net?

Comment: VBA for Excel. Sorry, I thought I was in VBA Topic.

Comment: np, I added a tag for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `RedimObj` method only resizes the array but it does not create new instances of `Obj` for each element.
So, when you call the `SetObjConlicit` property, the element pointed to by `LObj(index)` has a value of `Nothing` and you get that error.

So, you have to ensure that the object has already been constructed before accessing its `ObConlicita` property.

In order to do that, you can, for instance (see if it makes sense for your case), check if the element has been initialized first and, if not, initialize it. Example:

```
Public Property Let SetObjConlicit(ByVal index As Integer, ByVal ObjConlicit As Double)
    ' Check is element is initialized
    If LObj(index) Is Nothing Then
        ' and initialize it if it is not.
        Set LObj(index) = New Obj
    End If
    LObj(index).ObConlicita = ObjConlicit
End Property
```